# Passing along a function to a specific object

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's one of those times where I want to do soemthing, but I'm not sure what it's called...

Hopefully, someone can help!

**I have the following function:**

```
function myfunction(object1, object2) { ... }
```

I want to pass another function onto object1 specifically using the **.click** method.

I can get this working easily with only one object within the function using the following:

```
function myFunction(object1) { ... }

$('button').click(function() {
    // Passes along another function!
    myFunction(anotherFunction());
});
```

How would someone approach this when there are 2 objects? I can't seem to get anything working. Any ideas? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: If you want to pass the function, and *not* the result of the function, take the `()` off of the `anotherFunction` when you pass it.

Comment: "pass another function onto object1" does not mean anything to me.  If you want to use the result of a function call as the value of this parameters, then your example already does it, and it's trivial to pass `aThirdFunction()` as the value of the parameter `object2`, the same way you did with `anotherFunction()` for `object1`: `myFunction(anotherFunction(), aThirdFunction())`.  If you want something different, could you explain it differently than "pass a function onto an object"?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Assuming still:

```
function myFunction( function, anotherFunction, ... ) { ... }
```

If you want to pass specific arguments but be able to omit arguments, you could provide an argument but catch it as falsy:

```
myFunction( null, someOtherFunction, maybeAnotherFunction )
```

You then would need to handle the `null`, perhaps:

```
function myFunction( function, anotherFunction, ... ) {
    let fnc = function;
    let fnc2 = anotherFunction;
    let ... = ...;


    if(fnc) ...
    if(fnc2) ...
    if(...) ...      

    ...
}
```

**Original Answer**

Because you are triggering the function immediately during its passing you might actually want to just send it without initializing it. Try the below and see if this works for you.

```
function myFunction(object1, object2) {
    object1()
    object2()
}

$('button').click(function() {
    // Passes along another function!
    myFunction(anotherFunction1, anotherFunction2);
});
```

Comment: I'm looking to pass a function onto one of the objects only. For instance, anotherFunction1 to object1... Nothing more. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I might be confused on the ask. Do you mean you want to be able to omit object1 and still be able to use object2?

Comment: Yes. My primary function (myFunction) actually prints XML data. object1 and object2 are individual filters that customize the data output. I need to be able to pass functions onto those objects individually.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit strange to me. When you say passing functions on to object I am not completely sure what that means.

In terms of omission of arguments you could need to provide a value that you expect and then reject the expectation. If you provide 1 argument when 2 is expected, the first argument will be run.

Comment: Oh ok. So my question would then be, how does one add a function to a specific argument, when there are two arguments? Would that make more sense?

Comment: I updated my answer based on the concept of argument omission

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 5,
    b = 2;

function check(val1, val2) {
    console.log(val1);
    console.log(val2);
}

function add() {
    return a + b;
}

function mulitply() {
    return a * b;
}

check(add, mulitply); // this will send refernce of function's not output

check(add(), mulitply()); // this will converts into like this check(7,10);
```